# Search set in text column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have text column `geotargeting` that contains country codes separated by comma ("US,DE,CA,GB,IT"). If i have this input string "DE,CA,FR", I want to find all rows that contains one of the given countries.

Something like FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist) but i have 2 string lists.

Thanks.

Comment: Fix your data structure so you have an association table with one code per row per entity.  This will greatly help this and other queries on your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only way you have to use a stored procedure. Check this not ran this code but it can help you

```
SET @myArrayOfValue = 'US,DE,CA,GB,IT';
SET @myArrayOfValue1 = 'DE,CA,FR';

WHILE (LOCATE(',', @myArrayOfValue) > 0)
DO
    SET @value = ELT(1, @myArrayOfValue);
    SET @value = SUBSTRING(@myArrayOfValue, LOCATE(',',@myArrayOfValue) + 1);

    WHILE (LOCATE(',', @myArrayOfValue1 ) > 0)
    DO
        SET @value1 = ELT(1, @myArrayOfValue1 );
        SET @value1 = SUBSTRING(@myArrayOfValue1 , LOCATE(',',@myArrayOfValue1 ) + 1);
    END WHILE;

   IF(value = @value1) THEN    
      // the value match.. do something here, may be insert it in a temporary table
   END IF;
END WHILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    FUNCTION find_set_in_set (set_1 TEXT, set_2 TEXT)
    RETURNS BOOLEAN DETERMINISTIC

    BEGIN
        SET @i1 = LENGTH(set_1) - LENGTH(REPLACE(set_1, ',', '')) + 1;

        WHILE (@i1 > 0) DO
            SET @substr1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(set_1, ',', @i1), ',', -1);
            SET @i1 = @i1 - 1;
            SET @i2 = LENGTH(set_2) - LENGTH(REPLACE(set_2, ',', '')) + 1;

            WHILE (@i2 > 0) DO
                SET @substr2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(set_2, ',', @i2), ',', -1);
                SET @i2 = @i2 - 1;

                IF(@substr1 = @substr2) THEN
                    RETURN TRUE;
                END IF;
            END WHILE;
        END WHILE;

        RETURN FALSE;
    END
$$
```